# In Crest of the Stars, was it ever established what lies beyond the sords of the Milky Way?

Tags: crest-of-the-stars

In the anime *Crest of the Stars*, interstellar ships go through a dimension called 'plane space' to achieve FTL speeds and travel between stars in a reasonable time.

The 'sords', the entries into Plane Space, are roughly organized following the shape of the Milky Way. It was mentioned in one of the episodes of the anime that sords outside the Milky Way have been detected, possibly leading to other galaxies.

Was it ever established in-universe or out of universe if that was the case, or where they lead if not to another galaxy?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, and judging by the main novel series, no.

It is hard to completely understand from the text how the sords in Plane Space correspond with sords in the Galaxy itself (as it seems, coordinates of sord in 3D are barely related to coordinates in 2D), but all the known and reachable sords lead back to the Milky Way galaxy, so probably the sords of other galaxies are grouped together as well, and hard to reach even via 2D space.